# VB.NET Get the values of a multi-select list box

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I have a list box with milti select enabled, Im trying to create a TSQL command according to the selected values, I gen get the first selected value from the list box, how do i get the rest of the selected values.

```
Private Sub createSQLCMD(ByVal strServerName As String, ByVal 
strDatabaseName As String, ByVal strTableName As String)

    Dim strSQLCMD As String = "SELECT "

    For i As Integer = 0 To lstFieldList.Items.Count - 1
        If (lstFieldList.GetSelected(i)) And i < lstFieldList.Items.Count - 1 Then
            strSQLCMD &= lstFieldList.SelectedValue.ToString & ","

        End If
    Next
        strSQLCMD &= lstFieldList.SelectedValue.ToString
        txtSQLCMD.Text = strSQLCMD & " FROM " & strTableName
End Sub
```

Comment: There's actually nothing built into the `ListBox` class to do that. There's a `SelectedItems` property that is the multiple equivalent to the singular `SelectedItem`, but there's no `SelectedValues` equivalent to go with `SelectedValue`.  [Check this out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?851021) for a solution to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub createSQLCMD(ByVal strServerName As String, ByVal strDatabaseName As String, ByVal strTableName As String)
    Dim strSQLCMD As String = "SELECT "

    Dim selectedItems = lstFieldList.SelectedItems.Cast(Of String)

    'Dont forget to check if no item selected else you'll get an error.
    txtSQLCMD.Text = strSQLCMD & String.Join(",", selectedItems) & " FROM " & strTableName
End Sub
```